# Comprobar primer y último registro

Tags: mysql

**¿Cómo hago para sacar el primer registro de ingreso del día y el último registro de salida por mysql?**

---

Ésta es una consulta mas no una tabla.

```
$lstHoraEmp = array();

$sqlHorEmp = "SELECT DISTINCT(usuarios.Nombre), Documento, relacion_colaborador_horario.Id_Horario, horarios.Nombre Horario, Entrada, Salida FROM usuarios, relacion_colaborador_horario, horarios WHERE usuarios.Id_Usuario = relacion_colaborador_horario.Id_Usuario AND relacion_colaborador_horario.Id_Horario = horarios.Id_horario";
```

Ésta es una tabla de sql

```
$sqlr = 'select * from registros order by dia, hora, Nombres ASC';

$resr = mysql_query($sqlr,$con);
```

Comment: Con algo de experiencia en un sistema de asistencia de personal, donde los horarios de entrada y salida eran variados según el tipo de personal, te recomendaría crear una tabla donde se ingrese un turno (mañana, tarde, noche, otro) junto a su hora de entrada y la hora de salida y el limite de entrada y salida  (retraso y horas extras), y pues gracias a esa tablas tendrás tu sistema mas completo y ademas de que consultas como la que planteas serán mas fáciles de realizar.

Comment: se puede hacer con un for, con un query directo.. deberías especificar que tipo de solución buscas exactamente, y de paso escribir algo del código que intentaste, mas el formato de tu tabla o vector de datos. mira [ask]

Comment: Ahora que modificaste la pregunta. La respuesta que tienes no te sirve? que parte de tu codigo te esta dando problemas? se claro por favor.

Comment: La hora que me está imprimiendo en la tabla no concuerda con la hora del ingreso o salida del usuario.
O me aparece sólo que llegó tarde pero no que salió temprano, o viceversa.

Comment: Ok. Vamos a necesitar ejemplos de eso, de los datos, y que aclares que tipo de solucion queres. Porque tu query original ni siquiera esta filtrando los datos para un dia solo.

Comment: Ok, ¿Qué ejemplos necesitan o qué datos requieren para poder realizarlo? 

Si de pronto alguien por interno me pueda ayudar me serviría bastante. 

Gracias

Comment: Puedes agregar ejemplos de los datos que tienes en las tablas y el resultado actual que se muestra al ejecutar el código?

Comment: ¿De todas las tablas o de algunas en especial?

Comment: Si puedes de todas las que utilizas sería genial, pero las que me interesan ver son `horarios` y `registros`... por el momento. :)

Comment: Ok, voy a omitir unas cosas de éste ejemplo para poner lo que aparece en la base de datos

Comment: Lo hice lo más detallado posible.

Comment: En la tabla `HORARIOS` me parece que faltan datos de `Entrada` y `Salida`, o esas columnas pueden tener valores nulos?

Comment: Lo siento, ya lo agregué.

Comment: ¿Agrego las consultas que tengo en la BASE DE DATOS para relacionar las tablas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviando el código y lo que buscas obtener, me parece que te estás complicando más de lo que debieras.

Para obtener la información que quieres mostrar se puede utilizar una única consulta que es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
    t.Nombre,
    t.Documento,
    t.Dia,
    MAX(t.Entrada) Entrada,
    MAX(t.Salida) Salida,
    MAX(t.HorarioEntrada) HorarioEntrada,
    MAX(t.horarioSalida) HorarioSalida,
    t.Horario
FROM
(
    SELECT
        u.Nombre,
        u.Documento,
        r.Dia,
        IF(r.Tipo = 'Entry', r.Hora, NULL) Entrada,
        IF(r.Tipo = 'Exit', r.Hora, NULL) Salida,
        h.Entrada HorarioEntrada,
        h.Salida HorarioSalida,
        h.Nombre Horario
    FROM
        USUARIOS u
        INNER JOIN RELACION_HORARIOS rh ON (u.Id_Usuario = rh.Id_Usuario)
        INNER JOIN HORARIOS h ON (rh.Id_Horario = h.Id_Horario)
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                Documento,
                Tipo,
                Dia,
                IF(Tipo = 'Entry', MIN(Hora), MAX(Hora)) Hora
            FROM 
                REGISTROS
            GROUP BY
                Documento, Tipo, Dia
        ) r ON(r.Documento = u.Documento)
    WHERE
        (r.Tipo = 'Entry' AND r.Hora > h.Entrada)
        OR (r.Tipo = 'Exit' AND r.Hora < h.Salida)
) t
GROUP BY 
    t.Nombre,
    t.Documento,
    t.Dia,
    t.Horario
ORDER BY
    t.Dia DESC,
    t.Nombre ASC
```

La consulta realiza la unión de las tablas y muestra sólo los registros de los usuarios que han entrado tarde o se han ido temprano. Con esta consulta sólo debes ejecutarla desde php y mostrar la información.

Si tienes algún problema me avisas.

Comment: Hay un problema y es que tome sólo el primer registro del día y el último... Si la persona sale o entra DENTRO DEL HORARIO ASIGNADO que no me lo muestre, por ejemplo: El día **2017-06-02**, Si la entrada es a las 7 AM y entró a las 7:15 que sólo muestre la entrada de las 7:15 y que ya no muestre más registros **DE ENTRADA DE ESE DÍA** y que tome ya el último registro de salida... Por ejemplo, el mismo día debía salir a las 17:00:00 pero salió a las 16:59:00, que le genere error... 

**EL PRIMER REGISTRO DE "X" DÍA Y EL ÚLTIMO DEL MISMO DÍA** Y así con todos los días.

Comment: Ummm, lo que mencionas es un reto más interesante. Actualicé la consulta para utilizar sólo el primer o último registro del día. Me comentas que tal te va.

Comment: **ME SALE ESTO**

consulta SQL:

**EN LA MITAD EL CÓDIGO QUE ME DISTE PERO POR LA CANTIDAD DE CARACTERES NO ME DEJA PONERLO**


#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Salida)
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 30

Comment: Lo copié a la respuesta mal... xD Prueba de nuevo. En estos momentos no tengo una base de datos mysql para probar el código. :/

Comment: Tranquilo, yo le mando el error y usted lo mira. Gracias... Ya reviso a ver

Comment: ¿Y eso lo debo imprimir por un **while** o por un **for**?

Comment: Puedes imprimirlo con cualquiera de los dos. En el código que pusiste en la pregunta veo que utilizaste **while** `while($rowHorEmp = mysql_fetch_array($resHorEmp))`. Puedes realizar algo similar con esta consulta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63632/discussion-between-ceortiz-and-jemonge).

Comment: Tengo problemas con el Chat, disculpa.

Comment: Tranquilo, ahora, una persona X incumplió el horario completo todo un día... **2017-06-02**, Entró tarde y salió temprano, pero el registro me aparece en dos filas diferentes, la idea es que en una sola fila aparezcan los datos de las personas que incumplieron ambos horarios... Por ejemplo. **Debía entrar a las 07:00:00 pero entró a las 07:15:00 y ese mismo día debía salir a las 17:00:00 y salió a las 16:36:00... Que me aparezca en una sola fila y no en dos**

Comment: Tan sencilla que tenía la consulta, ahora se volvió algo compleja.. jeje... Acabo de actualizar la consulta con nuevos cambios.

Comment: Jaja es que voy haciendo y van saliendo cositas... Por ejemplo un error en el PHP **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Entry' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\Tardanzas.php on line 7**

Comment: Si esta consulta ya devuelve los datos que necesitas, lo mejor será dejar ésta pregunta por finalizada. Si tienes más problemas, publica una nueva pregunta en el sitio. ;)

Comment: Dale, muchas gracias... Voy a intentar y si no puedo de una publico una pregunta más... ¿Por casualidad me podés dar tu correo electrónico?

Comment: En mi perfil tengo publicado mi correo. Saludos.

Comment: Mi hermano, una última pregunta... ¿Cómo separo la hora de entrada y salida en diferente celda? Es que en una sola consulta aparece **HORARIO: 07:45:00 - 18:30:00** Necesito que me quede **ENTRADA Y SALIDA** separados (la última columna) Y aparte que después de esa aparezca el nombre del horario

Comment: Ya voté... ¿Si tomó la votación?

Comment: Sí, excelente... gracias. :)

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta es inconclusa pero creo saber lo que necesitas. Lo puedes hacer fácil con una consulta:

```
SELECT 
MIN(FECHA_ENTRADA) AS 'HORARIO DE ENTRADA'
MIN(FECHA_SALIDA) AS 'HORARIO DE SALIDA'
FROM EMPLEADOS 
WHERE ID_EMPLEADO = 123456
AND 
(FECHA_ENTRADA BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY OR
FECHA_SALIDA BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Te traes la primera fecha de entrada y la primera fecha de salida del empleado 123456 que corresponde al día de hoy, sin importar cuantas veces pasó su credencial o huella u iris o lengua, siempre será la primera fecha registrada de hoy.

Si necesitas un día en específico, juega con el `BETWEEN del WHERE`

Que te sirva

Comment: Este query falla si se ejecuta durante la tarde y el empleado entro un día temprano y al otro día mas tarde, porque no especifica sobre que día se esta buscando. por eso esperamos que siempre OP aclare la pregunta antes de contestarle. Mas allá de eso, gracias por aportar una solución.

Comment: Tienes razón, pero eso es tema para otra pregunta, creo que con esto, se le está dando solución a lo que está preguntando.

Comment: Nunca uses BETWEEN cuando filtros fechas; usa desigualdades

Comment: ¿Qué parte de la pregunta está inconclusa?

Comment: porque @Barranka?

Comment: @gbianchi porque si hay horas en el valor del campo puedes tener resultados inesperados. Lee este artículo: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Comment: esta bien.. es lo mismo que puse en mi primer comentario @Barranka.