# Error al subir archivo csv a mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el Index y el php en un sólo script.
Tengo un botón que me da la opción de buscar en el directorio el archivo csv para subir a la base de datos.

Antes de seleccionar el archivo me aparece el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: excel in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 30

Luego selecciono el archivo csv y le doy **"Subir archivo"** Y empieza a cargar.

Cuando termina me aparecen los siguientes errores:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php
>   on line 86
>
> **Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 88**
>
> **Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 89**
>
> **Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 89**
>
> **Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 90**
>
> **Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 92**
>
> **Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 86**
>
> **Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 88**
>
> **Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 89**
>
> **Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 89**
>
> **Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 90**
>
> **Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 92**
>
> **Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 86**

Y así por el numero de filas y columnas que tenga el archivo CSV.

¿Cuál es mi pregunta?

Si el archivo CSV tiene por ejemplo 100 archivos
¿Porqué me suben los 100 archivos (o el numero que sea) a la base de datos ***SIN NINGÚN ERROR O PÉRDIDA DE DATO*** pero me aparece ese error o noticia?

**ESTO ES EL CÓDIGO**

```
 < script type="text/javascript" >

$(function(){
        $("#btnEnviar").click(function(){
            $("#cuerpoPagina").load('procesar.php',$("#frmAsignar").serialize());
        })
    });
        function subirArchivoExcel()
            {
            if (document.frmSubirArchivo.excel.value == "") 
                {
                alert("¡Error!. ¡Debe subir un archivo!");
                document.frmSubirArchivo.excel.focus();
                return false;
                }

            document.frmSubirArchivo.action="procesar.php";
            document.frmSubirArchivo.submit();
            }
    </ script >
<?php

echo '  <form name="frmSubirArchivo" action"procesar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p >Archivo excel</ p>
            <p ><input type="file" name="excel" /></ p>
            <p ><input type="button" name="btnEnviar" id="btnEnviar" value="Subir Archivo" onclick="subirArchivoExcel();" ></ p>
        </form>';

include 'Conexion.php';

if (substr($_FILES['excel']['name'],-3)=="csv") 
    {
    $fecha      = date('Y-m-d');
    $hora       = time("HH:MM:SS");
    $carpeta    = "Ejemplo/";
    $carpeta    = "";
    $excel      = $fecha."-".$hora."-".$_FILES['excel']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'], "$carpeta$excel");

    //echo "$carpeta$excel";

    //print_r($_FILES);

    $contador = 0;
    $row      = 1;

    $fp = fopen("$carpeta$excel", "r");

    $meses = array( 'ENERO'         => '01',
                    'FEBRERO'       => '02',
                    'MARZO'         => '03',
                    'ABRIL'         => '04',
                    'MAYO'          => '05',
                    'JUNIO'         => '06',
                    'JULIO'         => '07',
                    'AGOSTO'        => '08',
                    'SEPTIEMBRE'    => '09',
                    'OCTUBRE'       => '10',
                    'NOVIEMBRE'     => '11',
                    'DICIEMBRE'     => '12');

    //echo $dias;

    //fgetcsv. obtiene los valores que estan en el csv y los extrae

    while ($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ";")) 
        {
        //Si la línea es igual a 5 no guardamos porque serian los títulos de la hoja de excel
        if ($row >= 7) 
            {
            //print_r("<pre>Row: ".$row);
            //print_r($data);
            //print_r("</pre>");

            // TEXTO:   jueves, 01 de junio de 2017 21:38
            $laFecha = explode(",", $data[1]);

            $fecArchivo = explode(" ", $laFecha[1]);
            //print_r($fecArchivo);
            $anno = $fecArchivo[5];
            $mes  = $meses[strtoupper($fecArchivo[3])];
            $dia  = $fecArchivo[1];

            $hora = $fecArchivo[6];

            $fechaReal = $anno."-".$mes."-".$dia;

            //echo $fechaReal;

            //echo $contador." - ";

            $sql_guardar  = 'INSERT INTO registros  (   Dia,
                                                        Hora,
                                                        Tipo_Acceso,
                                                        Puerta,
                                                        Tipo,
                                                        Tarjeta,
                                                        Nombres,
                                                        Apellidos,
                                                        Documento,
                                                        Empresa)';
            $sql_guardar .=         'VALUES(            "'.$fechaReal.'",
                                                        "'.$hora.'",
                                                        "'.$data[2].'",
                                                        "'.$data[3].'",
                                                        "'.$data[6].'",
                                                        "'.$data[7].'",
                                                        "'.$data[8].'",
                                                        "'.$data[9].'",
                                                        "'.$data[10].'",
                                                        "'.$data[12].'")';

            $contador++;

            //echo "7: ->".$data[7]."<- 10:->".$data[10]."<-";

            if ($data[7] != '') 
                {
                //echo $sql_guardar;

                //print_r("<pre>");
                //  print_r($sql_guardar);
                //print_r("</pre>");

                mysql_query($sql_guardar) or die(mysql_error());

                if (!$sql_guardar)
                    {
                    echo '<div>¡Hubo un problema al momento de importar el archivo! 
                            <br>¡Por favor vuelva a intentarlo!</div>';
                    exit;
                    }
                }
            }

        $row++;

        }

    fclose($fp);
    echo '<div>¡La importación del archivo se subió satisfactoriamente!</div>';
    exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Todo parece indicar que el archivo no está siendo enviado correctamente. Has actualizado el php.ini y has puesto la opción de permitir archivos en el formulario? Sería mejor que agregaras más código para poder ver las declaraciones de las variables que dan problemas.

Comment: Si, php.ini está bien hasta donde sé...

Y si, si me está dejando subir TODOS LOS ARCHIVOS, que eso es lo que me parece más raro. Si el archivo CSV tiene 100 filas y 10 columnas, me sube TODOS LOS DATOS en el lugar que es y completos

Comment: ¿Sabe qué es lo raro? Que si separo el index del php me funciona también pero sólo cambia que ya no muestra "Notice: Undefined index: excel in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro_2\procesar.php on line 30"

Comment: Puedes agregar la parte del código donde declaras `$laFecha` y le asignas su valor?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que de la línea 86 a la 92 me está convirtiendo una fecha de letras en números.
En el archivo CSV aparece por ejemplo "miércoles, 09 de Agosto del 2017  11:30"
Lo que hace es convertirlo en formato de sql, así: 2017/08/09

Comment: Todos los errores menos la línea 30 son provocados porque `$laFecha` no tiene datos.

Comment: Claro, la variable $laFecha tiene un valor: $laFecha = explode(",", $data[1]);

Aparte de eso, repito, no tengo problemas con los datos porque me los convierte bien y los sube correctamente, el verdadero problema es ¿Porqué me aparece ese error si me sube todo correctamente?

Comment: Qué tengas en el código `$laFecha = explode(",", $data[1]);` no quiere decir que `$laFecha` siempre tenga datos. Puede darse el caso que `$data` no tenga datos o no tenga "," para generar el array con el `explode`.

Comment: ¿Pero entonces cómo me explicas que no me genere ningún problema a la hora de subir los datos a MySQL? 
Porque me sube la fecha, la hora, y los demás campos...

Comment: Yo digo lo que veo con los errores que muestras. Es difícil decir cuál es el problema sin el código completo.

Comment: Voy a editar la publicación con el código completo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo dos problemas en tu código:

1. Tienes que evitar ejecutar substr($_FILES['excel']['name'],-3)=="csv" si aún no se ha enviado un archivo.
2. De la manera que lees el archivo, podría ser que en algunas líneas no obtengas el campo que tiene una fecha. Con el siguiente código puedes comprobarlo, en caso de no encontrar una fecha te lo mostrará:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" >

   $(function(){
       $("#btnEnviar").click(function(){
           $("#cuerpoPagina").load('procesar.php',$("#frmAsignar").serialize());
       })
   });

       function subirArchivoExcel()
       {
           if (document.frmSubirArchivo.excel.value == "") 
           {
           alert("¡Error!. ¡Debe subir un archivo!");
           document.frmSubirArchivo.excel.focus();
           return false;
           }

           document.frmSubirArchivo.action="procesar.php";
           document.frmSubirArchivo.submit();
       }
   </script>
   <?php

   echo '<form name="frmSubirArchivo" action"procesar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <p >Archivo excel</ p>
               <p ><input type="file" name="excel" /></ p>
               <p ><input type="button" name="btnEnviar" id="btnEnviar" value="Subir Archivo" onclick="subirArchivoExcel();" ></ p>
       </form>';

   include 'Conexion.php';

   if (isset($_FILES['excel']) && !empty($_FILES['excel']) && substr($_FILES['excel']['name'],-3)=="csv")
   {
       $fecha      = date('Y-m-d');
       $hora       = time("HH:MM:SS");
       $carpeta    = "Ejemplo/";
       $carpeta    = "";
       $excel      = $fecha."-".$hora."-".$_FILES['excel']['name'];

       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'], "$carpeta$excel");

       //echo "$carpeta$excel";

       //print_r($_FILES);

       $contador = 0;
       $row      = 1;

       $fp = fopen("$carpeta$excel", "r");

       $meses = array( 'ENERO'         => '01',
                       'FEBRERO'       => '02',
                       'MARZO'         => '03',
                       'ABRIL'         => '04',
                       'MAYO'          => '05',
                       'JUNIO'         => '06',
                       'JULIO'         => '07',
                       'AGOSTO'        => '08',
                       'SEPTIEMBRE'    => '09',
                       'OCTUBRE'       => '10',
                       'NOVIEMBRE'     => '11',
                       'DICIEMBRE'     => '12');

       //echo $dias;

       //fgetcsv. obtiene los valores que estan en el csv y los extrae

       while ($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ";"))
       {
           //Si la línea es igual a 5 no guardamos porque serian los títulos de la hoja de excel
           if ($row >= 7) 
           {
               //print_r("<pre>Row: ".$row);
               //print_r($data);
               //print_r("</pre>");

               // TEXTO:   jueves, 01 de junio de 2017 21:38
               $laFecha = explode(",", $data[1]);

               if(count($laFecha) == 2)
               {
                   $fecArchivo = explode(" ", $laFecha[1]);
                   //print_r($fecArchivo);
                   $anno = $fecArchivo[5];
                   $mes  = $meses[strtoupper($fecArchivo[3])];
                   $dia  = $fecArchivo[1];

                   $hora = $fecArchivo[6];

                   $fechaReal = $anno."-".$mes."-".$dia;

                   //echo $fechaReal;

                   //echo $contador." - ";

                   $sql_guardar  = 'INSERT INTO registros  (   Dia,
                                                               Hora,
                                                               Tipo_Acceso,
                                                               Puerta,
                                                               Tipo,
                                                               Tarjeta,
                                                               Nombres,
                                                               Apellidos,
                                                               Documento,
                                                               Empresa)';
                   $sql_guardar .=         'VALUES(            "'.$fechaReal.'",
                                                               "'.$hora.'",
                                                               "'.$data[2].'",
                                                               "'.$data[3].'",
                                                               "'.$data[6].'",
                                                               "'.$data[7].'",
                                                               "'.$data[8].'",
                                                               "'.$data[9].'",
                                                               "'.$data[10].'",
                                                               "'.$data[12].'")';

                   $contador++;

                   //echo "7: ->".$data[7]."<- 10:->".$data[10]."<-";

                   if ($data[7] != '') 
                   {
                       //echo $sql_guardar;

                       //print_r("<pre>");
                       //  print_r($sql_guardar);
                       //print_r("</pre>");

                       mysql_query($sql_guardar) or die(mysql_error());

                       if (!$sql_guardar)
                       {
                       echo '<div>¡Hubo un problema al momento de importar el archivo! 
                               <br>¡Por favor vuelva a intentarlo!</div>';
                       exit;
                       }
                   }
               }
               else
                   echo '<br>No se encontró una fecha válida en el dato: '.$data[1];

           }

           $row++;
       }

       fclose($fp);
       echo '<div>¡La importación del archivo se subió satisfactoriamente!</div>';
       exit;
   }
   ?>
   ```

Si tienes algún problema me avisas.

Comment: ¿Cómo hago para que no se haga por un submit (que se redireccione a otra página) si no que quede dentro del mismo index que estoy manejando?

Comment: Y una cosa más **:D** ¿Me podrías ayudar con el otro problema que tengo de otro PHP? por favor. **:D**

Comment: Para que no se redireccione a otra página debes utilizar Ajax, aquí hay información al respecto: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp. Cuál es el otro problema que mencionas?

Comment: Acá está en la otra página la pregunta.  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93743/comprobar-primer-y-%C3%BAltimo-registro

Comment: ¿Y dónde o cómo metería el $_GET?

Comment: No me queda claro a cuál $_GET te refieres? En el enlace que te compartí debes utilizar el método POST para enviar los datos al servidor.

Comment: SI, entiendo, pero necesito que no me cargue ni redireccione a otra página si no que me la deje en la misma. Entonces por lo que tengo entendido con el **$_GET** puedo hacer eso.

Comment: Sí, para que no redireccione ni cargue a otra página debes utilizar `Ajax` con el método `POST`, porque además estás buscando subir archivos, `$_GET` no lo necesitas. En el siguiente enlace hay un ejemplo simple de su implemetación: https://www.studytutorial.in/how-to-submit-a-form-using-jquery-ajax-and-php, verás que en ningún momento se utiliza `$_GET`. Intenta adaptarlo a lo que necesitas y si tienes algún problema, crea una nueva pregunta en el sitio, ya que este tema se sale de la pregunta original.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias.